# Replace tags without an ending tag with span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do something that probably is not possible, but here goes nothing.

Let's say I have this dummy text: "{red}Test {default}Message" (without quotation marks)
I would like a (jQuery) script to replace the {red} with a span and add a closing tag. the P element would be where the formatted test message would be.

E.G.

```
<p><span style="color:red;">Test</span> <span style="color:white;">Message</span></p>
```

I've searched all over the internet and I could only find HTML elements getting replaced with other HTML elements. (Or similar to that).
I haven't tried something yet, because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Is there `{red}` or `<red>` ?

Comment: You probably will need RegExp (regular expressions)

Comment: It's {red}. And yes I expected the RegExp, but how do I add the ending tag dynamically?

Comment: To get you started on this here is a suggestion:
you can create 2d array out of your text and then iterate through it and create element based on the color add style to your element. Hope it helps

Comment: Where should be the closing tag?

Comment: After the new tag starts. In this case {default} (that's the hard part I suppose)

Comment: use `(?!text)`(not followed by) or just `[^{]`(not a { braclet) regex part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: use `initial` color instead of `default`.

```js
s = "{red}Test {initial}Message";
html = '<p>'+s.replace(/\{(\w*)\}([^{]*)/g,'<span style="color:$1">$2</span>')+'</p>'

document.body.innerHTML=html;
// inherit
s = "<br>{red}Red {initial}Initial and {inherit}Inherited colors";
html = '<p style="color:orange">'+s.replace(/\{(\w*)\}([^{]*)/g,'<span style="color:$1">$2</span>')+'</p>'

document.body.innerHTML+=html;
//with own colors
colors={
  red:'#5f0',
  green:'purple'
};
s = "<br>{red}Red {green}Green and {orange}orange colors";
html = '<p>'+s.replace(/\{(\w*)\}([^{]*)/g,function(s,s1,s2){
  if(colors[s1])
    s1=colors[s1];
  return '<span style="color:'+s1+'">'+s2+'</span>'
})+'</p>'

document.body.innerHTML+=html;
```

Comment: You are, amazing. A side question, is there a way I can specify HEX colors. e.g. red = #EA4B4B

Comment: You may use `{#EA4B4B}` easily OR use function. Do you need this function?

Comment: Right, so it needs to be saved to the database as {red}Test {default}Tag. I only want to show users in the front end, the exact color it's going to be. (Default is white in this case)

Comment: @Joram , Updated. Added fn.